# Prevent Highchart.js from cutting xAxis label

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I want to only show the first and last label for the xAxis. Then, I want to show it without rotation and in a single line. And when I do this, this happens and the last label gets cut when there are many columns or the width of the viewport is small.

[image]

Demo online:
https://jsfiddle.net/8esnf4dj/

This is my xAxis config:

```js
xAxis: {
      categories: [....],
      labels: {
          rotation: 0,
          style: {
            textOverflow: 'none',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
          },
     }
}
```

Is there any way to align the text in a way that this won't happen?

I've seen that this can be fixed by adding `chart.marginRight` but I would rather prefer not to "lose" that space not the right and just align the text in a way that will always be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible to achieve it by using only API options, because all the labels are rendered in the center of the tick, but you can move/set the position of each label 'manually'.

```
    events: {
        render() {
            const chart = this;
            const xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
            const lastTickPosition = xAxis.tickPositions.length - 1;
            const lastLabel = chart.xAxis[0].ticks[lastTickPosition].label;
            
            lastLabel.translate(-lastLabel.getBBox().width/ 4, 0)
        }
    }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kbn7zwfc/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Working great! Thanks!

Comment: One question tho. Why do you divide `-lastLabel.getBBox().width` between 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "align: right"
Read the usage of [align](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.align) to understand why this works. Basically this would mean that the bar would align to the rightmost end of the label so the label always fits

```
xAxis: {
      categories: [....],
      labels: {
          rotation: 0,
          align: "right",
          style: {
            textOverflow: 'none',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
          },
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but then the one that gets cut is the one on the very left.  See this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/2p0bxayz/